# How to generate a keypair correctly with Stellar/go?

Tags: go-sdk, keypair, seed

Take test seed here: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0005.md

**seed**:
"e0eec84fe165cd427cb7bc9b6cfdef0555aa1cb6f9043ff1fe986c3c8ddd22e3"

**correct result**:
m/44'/148'/0'
GDRXE2BQUC3AZNPVFSCEZ76NJ3WWL25FYFK6RGZGIEKWE4SOOHSUJUJ6
SBGWSG6BTNCKCOB3DIFBGCVMUPQFYPA2G4O34RMTB343OYPXU5DJDVMN

How to properly turn **seed** into a **correct result** (keypair)?
Trying:

```
import (
    "github.com/stellar/go/keypair"
)
var seeds [32]byte
copy(seeds[:], []byte("e0eec84fe165cd427cb7bc9b6cfdef0555aa1cb6f9043ff1fe986c3c8ddd22e3"))
pair, err := keypair.FromRawSeed(seeds)
xlmAddr := pair.Address()
xlmPK := pair.Seed()
fmt.Println(xlmAddr)
fmt.Println(xlmPK)
```

Result is different...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone will need it,

https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/3478

I tried to change it to this:

```
xlmSeed, _ := hex.DecodeString("e0eec84fe165cd427cb7bc9b6cfdef0555aa1cb6f9043ff1fe986c3c8ddd22e3")
xlmKey, err := xlmDrv.DeriveForPath(xlmDrv.StellarPrimaryAccountPath, xlmSeed)
pair, err := keypair.FromRawSeed(xlmKey.RawSeed())
fmt.Println(pair.Seed())
fmt.Println(pair.Address())
Still the wrong result.
```

But it turned out to be wrong...

overcat(Jun Luo) answered in my question:

*You should use BIP39 Seed in SEP-05, not m/44'/148' key. If you want to reproduce test 1 in SEP-10, please use the following code.*

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stellar/go/exp/crypto/derivation"
    "github.com/stellar/go/keypair"
)

func main() {
    // I ignored all errors.
    bip39Seed, _ := hex.DecodeString("e4a5a632e70943ae7f07659df1332160937fad82587216a4c64315a0fb39497ee4a01f76ddab4cba68147977f3a147b6ad584c41808e8238a07f6cc4b582f186")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        path := fmt.Sprintf(derivation.StellarAccountPathFormat, i)
        key, _ := derivation.DeriveForPath(path, bip39Seed)
        keyPair, _ := keypair.FromRawSeed(key.RawSeed())
        fmt.Printf("%s %s %s\n", path, keyPair.Address(), keyPair.Seed())
    }
}
```

*Actually m/44'/148' key is the intermediate value generated during the calculation, if you are interested in it, add a breakpoint here and explore k.Key.*